# Apache Camel deleteAfterRead does not work

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel

So I want to fetch file from Amazon S3 Bucket and delete it (use s3 as a queue). 
The huge problem is that the Apache Camel is receiving same messages and does not try to delete them.

Here we have route
`from("aws-s3://bucket?amazonS3Client=#s3Client&deleteAfterRead=true")` with a flag.

The whole route is

```
from("aws-s3://bucket?amazonS3Client=#s3Client&deleteAfterRead=true")
        .to("seda:queue");
```

I even tried to add processor that reads the inputstreams (though it could help to read and delete)

```
.process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    InputStream stream = (InputStream) exchange.getIn().getBody();
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(IOUtils.toString(stream));
                }
            })
```

Also I have Camel Context file. Here it is.

```
<bean id="awsRegion" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="getRegion"/>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>us-west-1</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="s3Client" class="com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
                <constructor-arg value="${access.key}"/>
                <constructor-arg value="${secret.key}"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
<!-- enable Spring @Component scan -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.titan.router"/>

    <camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <!-- and then let Camel use those @Component scanned route builders -->
        <contextScan/>
        <consumerTemplate id="consumer"/>
        <template id="producer"/>
        <threadPoolProfile id="titanRouterProfile" poolSize="20" maxPoolSize="50" maxQueueSize="-1"/>
    </camelContext>
```

**UPD1**
The funny thing is that if I remove second queue and pass object to end then the object will be removed. 
`from("queue?amazonS3Client=#s3Client").process(...).end();`
Then I checked the S3 Storage and I didn't find any files.

Comment: This is not a solution, but can you please try replace to with wireTap. I suppose that your aws-s3 client waits for response from seda:queue

Comment: Have you tried setting ExchangePattern.InOnly?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I fixed it by removing seda queue.